# Python, paramiko, invoke_shell and ugly characters

Tags: python, paramiko

When I run the Python code below:

```
import workflow
import console
import paramiko
import time

strComputer = 'server.com'
strUser = 'user'
strPwd = 'passwd'

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=strComputer, username=strUser, password=strPwd)

channel = client.invoke_shell()
channel.send('ls\n')
time.sleep(3)
output=channel.recv(2024)
print(output)

#Close the connection
client.close()
print('Connection closed.')
```

I get the desired output mixed with ugly characters:

```
Last login: Thu Jun 19 23:37:55 2014 from 192.168.0.10

ls
user@server:~$ ls
[0m[01;34mbin[0m                                         Rplots1.pdf
[01;32mbtsync[0m                                      Rplots.pdf
btsync.conf~                                [01;31mrstudio-server-0.95.265-amd64.deb[0m
[01;31mbtsync_glibc23_x64.tar[0m                      screen.vba
[01;34mbudget[0m                                      [01;34mshiny[0m
[01;3
Connection closed.
```

Can anyone explain me what is going on, and how to get a pretty output instead?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

those are terminal color codes used by `ls` to highlight directories, executable files etc. you can call `/bin/ls` (or, on some distributions, `ls --color=never`) explicitly to avoid calling aliases etc. and get un-colored output.

the colors are defined using those cryptic codes like `[0m[01;34m`.
here's how the terminal looks like when `ls` coloring is enabled:

[image]